# How to use XAMPP with copied site files

Tags: php, html, wordpress, xampp, localhost

I've installed XAMPP and whatever comes with it. I have copied files and database from a hosted WordPress site to my localhost XAMPP test environment. I have created the same user in the database to connect to it.

When i try to go to the directory on my browser (localhost/test) I am redirected to localhost/dashboard and not to my copied site.What do I do to get to my site?

Are there any files I should be changing and settings I should look at? I'm fairly new to this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you check htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just place this line in your wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

where `http://example.com` is your site name e.g. `http://localhost/test`

Comment: i made this changes in the database wp_options, i'll try adding this to wp-config.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace all URL into your database e.g

http://localhost/dashboard
to
http://localhost/test

I suggesting you to rename test to real name of your project, because some time test keyword not working perfect in Wordpress as it is reserved keyword

Comment: i changed home and siteurls values in wp-options in database to http://localhost/"sitename"/.  I imported the database so there shouldn't be dashboard values in there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to you phpMyadmin > Select your database > select wp_option table and see the first two row:1. siteurl an 2 Home, in the option value enter your url example:

siteurl : http://localhost/test
home: http://localhost/test

also check your wp-config file for correct database name and user